# Add custom fields to the taxRule entity

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

How is it possible to add custom data to any configured tax rule with different values? Sadly there is no customField property available at the taxRule entity.
Its possible to add customFields to the tax entity, but then this only can have one value for all configured countries.
Maybe there is another approch to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do and how it could be achieved is depending on two things:

- Are you developing a plugin or an app?

  - Does the user have to set the custom fields or would it be ok to set them using the API only?

---

###### With a plugin

If you're developing a plugin you could [extend the `TaxRuleDefinition`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities#adding-a-field-with-database) with an association to [a custom entity](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-custom-complex-data) with the fields of the custom entity essentially being your custom fields.

If you're ok with simply setting the fields of your custom entity via the API, you're good to go. Given your custom entity is called `tax_rule_custom_field`:

```json
// POST|PATCH /api/tax-rule-custom-fields
{
  "id": "...",
  "taxRuleId": "...",
  "customField": "...",
  "anotherCustomField": true
}
```

If you want the user to set these fields from within the UI of the administration, you'll have to extend the administration and [register custom components or override existing components](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-component) to inject the various fields where you want them to show up and make them persist when the user saves changes.

[I created an example plugin](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneCustomerHeightExtension) that adds additional fields to the customer in the same manner and injects input fields for them in the administration. The same basic principle could be used for tax rules.

###### With an app

If you're developing an app you may also [add a custom entity](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-entities) to contain your fields. However, as far as I know, you can't yet extend existing entities yet, like you can with a plugin, to add an association to the `TaxRuleDefinition`. So you'll have to resolve to loading and persisting the custom entity manually whenever needed, e.g. by [using app scripts](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts).

Furthermore you can't extend the administration directly as you can with plugins. You'll have to [add a custom module](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/administration/add-custom-modules), with the UI and logic for loading and persisting the fields of your custom entity being hosted on your app server entirely. That's where you may use the API as explained above, in the part about plugins, to persist and load data of your custom entity.

Comment: Thanks! I want to develop an App and thought I can easily skip all this hassle with an own module and just add a custom field. But dang it! this would be too easy. :(
My goal is to add a textfield to any taxrate including all countries that are setup at a tax rate. Super simple, but the lack of adding it as a custom Field makes it soooo complicated.

I think I have to think of another way then. Do you know why these fields dont come with customFields? I thought every entity is capable of such things to easily add custom stuff?